# ServiceStack - Empty Request Classes?

Tags: servicestack

I have a question regarding ServiceStack. Why are there empty Request Classes, why do we have to have a Request Class? For example:

```
[Route("/test", "GET")]
public class Test
{

}

public class TestResponse
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

public class TestService : Service
{
    public object Get(Test test)
    {
        return new TestResponse { Date = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
    }
}
```

If I don't pass an object with my request, my service fails?

Then I'm my Global.asax file, I have:

```
public class AxDataAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AxDataAppHost() :
        base("AxData", typeof(TestService).Assembly)
    {
    }
}
```

What if I have more than 1 service, in the example above I'm using `TestService` but what if I have one for `Customers`, `Orders` and `Products`? How do I handle multiple services?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**why do we have to have a Request Class?**

ServiceStack is a message-based framework that embraces [Martin Fowler's Remote Service Best Practices](http://www.slideshare.net/fullscreen/newmovie/what-istheservicestack-14819151/17) (i.e. Remote Facade, DTOs and Gateway) which utilizes a ServiceGateway to send coarse-grained Request DTOs which commonly returns a typed Response DTO (though [services can return anything](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-return-types)). Using a message-based design [has many advantages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services) and is what enables ServiceStack's typed end-to-end API.

E.g. you can re-use these types you defined your services with:

```
public class Test : IReturn<TestResponse> {}

public class TestResponse
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

On the client, which is what gives you a typed API without code-gen, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUri);
TestResponse response = client.Get(new Test());
```

*Note: you don't even need custom routes as by default ServiceStack's C# clients will fallback to use the [pre-defined routes](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#predefinedroutes) (enabled by default).*

**What if I have more than 1 service, in the example above I'm using TestService but what if I have one for Customers, Orders and Products? How do I handle multiple services?**

In your AppHost base constructor you're passing in an **assembly** (i.e. NOT a single service):

```
public AxDataAppHost() : base("AxData", typeof(TestService).Assembly) {}
```

This tells ServiceStack where to look for and wire-up all your services. You only need to do this once for each dll/assembly that your services are in.

ServiceStack's AppHosts also allows specifying multiple assemblies which you can use to wire-up services located in multiple assemblies, e.g:

```
public AxDataAppHost() 
  : base("AxData", typeof(TestService).Assembly, typeof(ServiceInNewDll).Assembly) {}
```

Comment: WOW! Excellent answer! Thanks for your detailed answer and the links! Really explained to me! :)

Comment: Good answer. I agree that the patterns you cite are important, and shaping services this way leads to a very clean design. However, sometimes you just need an endpoint to be called. 
I am implementing access to a 3rd party server using OAuth, and in ServiceStack I need to implement my request and callback as two services with two empty DTOs. Is this the right way to do it, or is there a better way?